# Best solution for send newsletter with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, newsletter, exim

please help me for best solution send newsletter never server exim banned and ip blocked ,i have share hosting, if you have a good script suggest me,t hank you every one

Comment: Mailchimp is what I suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use `Mailchimp` for Newsletters & `Mandrill` for Transactional Mails in our Codeigniter App.

You will also find api libraries available for codeigniter for [Mandrill](https://github.com/fideloper/CI-Mandrill) & [Mailchimp](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/MailChimp-API-v1.3-Library).

The other options are `PostMark`, `Sendgrid` etc which are easy too. It basically comes down to which is cheaper & that depends on your volume of email